# React Native charge component background

Tags: api, reactjs, background, calendar, native

I have a calendar module that first charges the calendar itself and then charges the events every day have fetching the data from an api. So what i want is that the calendar can charge background with a loading view until its fully charged so i can show it to the user. 
Any idea how to do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: charge or change?

Comment: charge with the meaning of loading it while the loading view is showing